# Serverless Lambda infrastructure for listening to Websocket

Tags: amazon-lambda, amazon-api-gateway

I'm still new in the AWS Lambda & Api Gateway world, but it seems a good fit to my new project.

I still have some concerns, and I'll be very happy if you can assist.

In my new project (Financial data), I need to deliver different type of data :

- Historical data (I was thinking of HTTP Api in AWS API GATEWAY)
- Live streaming data (I was thinking of WEBSOCKET Api in AWS API GATEWAY)
- Market opportunity, based on websocket data I RECEIVE and analyse (WEBSOCKET Api in AWS API GATEWAY)

Here are my questions :

1. In a serverless Lambda architecture, is it possible to LISTEN to websocket, then analyse the data, and send them back through the API Gateway websocket api ?
2. Is DynamoDB a good Fit for large amount of historical data ? I know it's fast, but is'nt it a waste for data that will not be updated anymore ?
3. Does it make more sense to use a "classic" nodejs framework, that manages REST and Websocket API, like SailsJs for example ?

Thanks a lot